# How to use the same numbering counter for figures, tables and listings?

Tags: numbering, listings, lstlisting

In other words, have:

Table 1
Table 2
Figure 3
Listing 4
Figure 5
etc...

I've currently got:

```
\makeatletter \let\c@table\c@figure\c@lstlisting \makeatother
```

But it only works for table and figures.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) `\let` takes only two arguments, so `\c@lstlisting` is left out. Here you are just setting `table` equal to `figure`, you'll need to use two `\let` statements

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\let` takes only two arguments (the one which is overwritten and the one which overwrites). So you need one line more.

Comment: i  like to discourage you to use one numbering counter for all. this will make troubles at reader. they will ask where is (hidden)  "figure 1", figure 2", etc.

Answer (score 4):

> `\makeatletter \let\c@table\c@figure\c@lstlisting \makeatother`

to complete the intended change you need two assignments

```
\makeatletter 
\let\c@table\c@figure
\let\c@lstlisting\c@figure
\makeatother
```

But even with just `figure` and `table` this assignment does not really work. It forces the environments to use the same number but they are different floats so latex will handle them separately and only keep tables in order with tables and figures in order with figures, so your document could have

> table 2 figure 1 table 3

if the first figure floats past the first table.

If you want the same counter you should tell latex to keep the floats in the same order, which means using the same float type, so the usual way is to put all your figure tables and listings in a `figure` environment so the document will have

> Figure 1 Figure 2 Figure 3

with the figures containing images or `tabular` depending on the content.

---

If you *really* want to use different named floats in the same order you also need

```
\let\ftype@table\ftype@figure
\let\ftype@listings\ftype@figure
```

But this will still be very confusing for anyone looking at tables and just seeing a non-continuous set of numbers.